# Display map scale (like 1:20.000) next to ScaleBar

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

In my PageLayoutControl I add a ScaleBar. Additionaly I like to show the map scale/ratio (e.g. "1:20.000") next to it, but didn't find a way to achieve this with the ScaleBar. Am I missing something or is there another way to do this?

Here is, how I add the ScaleBar:

```
  IEnvelope envelope = new EnvelopeClass();
  envelope.PutCoords(5, 0.1, 12.4, 1); // Specify the location and size of the scalebar
  IUID uid = new UIDClass();
  uid.Value = "esriCarto.ScaleLine";

  // Create a Surround. Set the geometry of the MapSurroundFrame to give it a location
  // Activate it and add it to the PageLayout's graphics container
  IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = pageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
  IActiveView activeView = pageLayout as IActiveView;
  IFrameElement frameElement = graphicsContainer.FindFrame(map);
  IMapFrame mapFrame = frameElement as IMapFrame;
  IMapSurroundFrame mapSurroundFrame = mapFrame.CreateSurroundFrame(uid as UID, null);
  IElement element = mapSurroundFrame as IElement;
  element.Geometry = envelope;
  element.Activate(activeView.ScreenDisplay);
  graphicsContainer.AddElement(element, 0);
  IMapSurround mapSurround = mapSurroundFrame.MapSurround;

  IScaleBar markerScaleBar = (IScaleBar)mapSurround;
  markerScaleBar.LabelPosition = esriVertPosEnum.esriBelow;
  markerScaleBar.UseMapSettings();
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer but there is some Java documentation on Map Surrounds that may hel at http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/engineexamples/controls.symbology.addmapsurrounds/example.html

Comment: @PolyGeo: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ScaleText](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000s9m000000) is the way to go. PolyGeo's link pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

I use the same code as above apart from setting a ScaleText instead of a ScaleLine (line 4)

```
uid.Value = "esriCarto.ScaleText";
```

and setting different Options (last paragraph):

```
IScaleText2 markerScaleText = (IScaleText2)mapSurround;
markerScaleText.Separator = ":";
markerScaleText.Style = esriScaleTextStyleEnum.esriScaleTextAbsolute;
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, the key information that pointed gumo in the right direction can be found in the [Add Map Surrounds](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/engineexamples/controls.symbology.addmapsurrounds/example.html) resource of ArcGIS Engine:

> This sample demonstrates using the SymbologyControl to display north
>   arrow,scale bar,and scale text symbols,which are used by custom
>   commands when adding MapSurround objects to the GraphicsContainer of
>   the PageLayout.The sample uses the SymbologyControl in conjunction
>   with the PageLayoutControl, TOCControl, ToolbarControl,and the
>   controls commands.